# Combining two js files (Of the same name, but at dirrefent locations) into a new file

Tags: javascript, html, file-handling

I have two javaScript files, say example.js at two locations:
`Result/Apr19/example.js` and
`Result/Apr20/example.js`

The content of the files is like(variable names being same, values are different):

**`Result/Apr19/example.js`** :`var regArr = ["A" , "B"]`

**`Result/Apr20/example.js`** : `var regArr = ["C" , "D"]`

I want to make a new file, say **`NewExapmle.js`** that has contents from both the files, with the variable names changed. Something like:

`var regArr1 = ["A" , "B"];`

`var regArr2 = ["C" , "D"];`

I read that javaScript has no access to file system. can someone suggest how to get this done. I have to use the final script NewExapmle.js in an HTML.

Comment: *"I read that javaScript has no access to file system."* Whatever you were reading was yet another example of people confusing *language* and *environment*. JavaScript *in the browser* doesn't have *direct* access to the file system. It does have indirect access (for instance, via `input type="file"`). JavaScript in other environments may well have direct access (like Node.js or Rhino/Nashorn running in a JVM).

Comment: Something like this is simply done manually. You create a new file, combine the contents of the two original files and modify any variable names as needed.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. When and where do you want to combine the files? At runtime in the browser? (If so, why not before then?) If so, will the code be running in a classic web setup, or from a file in the file system?

Comment: I want to give the folder names at run time (Result/Apr19 and Result/Apr20 in the question), and get a combined result. This is a small representation of what i need on a broader level. The file will be run on a file system, to display results in an HTML.

Comment: can you access the 2 files over the web browser with http?

Comment: As mentioned, I have both the files in my local file system.

Comment: Accessing, reading and combining the files is one thing (and not possible from within a web browser for security purposes), but then dynamically modifying the code to change variable names is something else entirely that is realistically not do-able.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Can you please answer how to combine the contents (what is asked in the question) and form NewExapmle.js with regArr1 and regArr2. I know what to do after that.

Comment: No, I can't because, as I said, that is not allowed in a browser due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are willing to move into a Javascript framework or library, I would suggest you use bash in a terminal window for performing what you are asking for.

In bash you can:

- Create varibles that stores your wanted folder names.
  (By using variables you can also add the date.)
- Copy your both files content, create a third file
  and add the content from both first files into the third file.
  (you will be using sed or awk for that, that are built-in tools in bash).